# kube-calico bird: Mesh_172_26_178_195: Socket error: bind: Address not available

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

Issue appears when kube-calico service on node trying to connect master: Dec 17 12:03:41 a docker[27052]: bird: Mesh_47_105_189_58: Socket error: bind: Address not available Dec 17 12:03:41 a docker[27052]: bird: Mesh_172_26_178_195: Socket error: bind: Address not available

Below is my etcd configuration on master (172.26.178.195:2379 is my private ip):

```
Description=Etcd Server
After=network.target
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
Documentation=https://github.com/coreos

[Service]
Type=notify
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/etcd/
ExecStart=/root/kubernetes/bin/etcd \
  --name=172.26.178.195 \
  --listen-client-urls=http://172.26.178.195:2379,http://127.0.0.1:2379 \
  --advertise-client-urls=http://172.26.178.195:2379 \
  --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
LimitNOFILE=65536


master:
Calico process is running.

IPv4 BGP status
+----------------+-------------------+-------+----------+---------+
|  PEER ADDRESS  |     PEER TYPE     | STATE |  SINCE   |  INFO   |
+----------------+-------------------+-------+----------+---------+
| 47.105.223.158 | node-to-node mesh | start | 02:49:30 | Connect |
| 47.105.189.58  | node-to-node mesh | start | 02:49:30 | Connect |
+----------------+-------------------+-------+----------+---------+

IPv6 BGP status
No IPv6 peers found.

node:
Calico process is running.

IPv4 BGP status
+----------------+-------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------------+
|  PEER ADDRESS  |     PEER TYPE     | STATE |  SINCE   |              INFO              |
+----------------+-------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------------+
| 47.105.189.58  | node-to-node mesh | start | 03:54:15 | Active Socket: Connection      |
|                |                   |       |          | closed                         |
| 172.26.178.195 | node-to-node mesh | start | 03:54:15 | Active Socket: Connection      |
|                |                   |       |          | closed                         |
+----------------+-------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------------+

IPv6 BGP status
No IPv6 peers found.
docker config for 'calico service':

[Service] User=root PermissionsStartOnly=true ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --net=host --privileged --name=calico-node \ -e ETCD_ENDPOINTS=47.92.52.24:2379 \ -e CALICO_LIBNETWORK_ENABLED=true \ -e CALICO_NETWORKING_BACKEND=bird \ -e CALICO_DISABLE_FILE_LOGGING=true \ -e CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR=172.20.0.0/16 \ -e CALICO_IPV4POOL_IPIP=always \ -e FELIX_DEFAULTENDPOINTTOHOSTACTION=ACCEPT \ -e FELIX_IPV6SUPPORT=false \ -e FELIX_LOGSEVERITYSCREEN=info \ -e FELIX_IPINIPMTU=1440 \ -e FELIX_HEALTHENABLED=true \
-e IP=47.105.223.158 \ -v /var/run/calico:/var/run/calico \ -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules \ -v /run/docker/plugins:/run/docker/plugins \ -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \ -v /var/log/calico:/var/log/calico \ registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/imooc/calico-node:v2.6.2 ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker rm -f calico-node Restart=always RestartSec=10
```

Any suggestions for this?

Comment: What cloud provider are you using?

Comment: It serves on Ali Cloud ECS service

Answer (score 0):

The calico/node use a public ip to communicate with each other. But nodes in AliCloud are behind a firewall. Some cloud providers block traffic between host by default, for example in GCE [firewall rule has to be created](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/gce). You should create firewall rule allowing communication between hosts.

Also use env var in calico/node container [`IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD`](https://docs.projectcalico.org/master/reference/node/configuration) to specify which interface/network to use.